# how to save file in different Encoding in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to save a file, with the below code, in different encoding, for example ANSI.
How can I do this, on Windows?

```
file=File.new("c:/ruby/hps.txt","w")
file.puts 'there is some text'
file.close
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [an example in the Encoding documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Encoding.html#class-Encoding-label-IO+encoding+example) about how to do this. [open](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-open), [File.new](https://ruby-doc.org/core/File.html#method-c-new), and [IO.new](https://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-c-new) all take the same mode and encoding arguments.

Using `File.open` with a block is safer and more succinct than managing the filehandle yourself.

```
File.open("c:/ruby/hps.txt", "w:ISO-8859-1") do |f|
  f.write("some text")
end
```

This example writes the string as [ISO 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) aka Windows-1252 aka Latin-1.

"ANSI" encoding is ambiguous. Check `Encoding.list` for what's available.